# how does goodreads work?

Tags: java, android, database

I am new to android studio and would like to make an app that is similar to Goodreads. Can someone outline the key components of making an app like this. It would also be great if I could get some kind of template that I can use. I imagine some of amount of the user information will be kept on the device while some of the other larger sets of information will be kept on a database. What would the code connecting these two parts look like and what other important parts have I missed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe start with a simpler app and a tutorial. This is far too broad a question.

Comment: @noob - Voting to close this because this question is way too broad. Please start with an android tutorial. Then look up MVC, which is a common design pattern to build apps. e.g, http://www.appstoremarketresearch.com/articles/android-tutorial-model-view-controller-architecture/

Comment: I'd argue MVP is more common on Android than MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is a big world  and doesn't exist an easy way, I mean all need time to be good at something, but well is not impossible I recommend you start with the Udacity courses

Basic Level:

[Developing Android Apps by  Google](https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851)

[Android Basics: Data Storage](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845)

[Android Basics: Multiscreen Apps](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-multiscreen-apps--ud839)

[Android Basics: Networking](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-networking--ud843)

and latter star to flow important people on android world
[Android expert](https://developers.google.com/experts/all/technology/kotlin) even follow in twitter

after that, you have a basic knowledge you can start on other courses https://caster.io/ is a good choice for learn  MVP MVVM and other things

also study general programming and Software Engineering : Desing Parrents, Clean Code , Clean Arquiecture, SOLID principles, Versions systems like a Git.
well that my advice for you, good luck  and never stop to learn!